# AJAX PHP file upload - file size?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Can't get my head around this,
HTML form (input file) using AJAX to send to PHP to be uploaded and then save path in a database - here is how the code looks at the minute.

HTML:

```
<form action="" id="upppic" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="ppic">Change Profile Picture</label>
    <input type="file" name="ppic">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

AJAX:

```
$(function() {
    $("form#upppic").submit(function() {
        $('#loading').show();
        var userid = localStorage.userid;
        var userid = 2;
        //disable the default form submission
        event.preventDefault();
        //grab all form data  
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://www.url.com/page.php?uid="+ userid,
          type: "POST", // Type of request to be send, called as method
          data: formData,
          dataType: "text",
          cache: false, 
          contentType: false,
          processData:false,
          crossDomain:true,
          success: function(data){
              alert(data);
              $('#loading').hide();},
          error: function (data){
              alert(data);
              $('#loading').hide();}
        });
    return false;
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,x-prototype-version,x-requested-with');

$uid=(int)$_GET['uid'];
if($uid>1)
{
echo "got here";}
```

The PHP is nothing at the minute (due to mass debugging) but as it runs currently files <= 53kb seem to upload ok and i get "got here alert". Any other sized file just returns [object object] and the console log says it was unable to connect with "page.php..."

PHP.INI file (in Root)

```
upload_max_filesize=100M
post_max_size=105M
max_execution_time=2000
max_input_time=2000
memory_limit=128M
```

Comment: Are you using amp package like xampp or something similar? Have you restarted your apache server after editing options? What do your error logs say?

Comment: @vove 123-reg shared hosting unfortunately. and error logs say nothing... literally...

Comment: Well, if there would be problem with your configuration it would produce error in php_error_log. Since you say it has nothing in it I would contact with 123-reg. I managed to save 3 GB in local using your code so that shouldn't be a problem. For the sake of everyone I strongly encourage you to start a local server (or even two if you need it) and do the testing on them- you have total control of the environment. If you send files to some server you have completely no control of troubleshooting will be close to impossible. Even though you should have access to some error log in control panel.

Comment: @vove thanks for your help and words of advice I shall achieve them all now, starting with contacting 123-reg.

Comment: Get yourself some amp package for your OS. It is way much easier to try out your code if you can control every factor and if you want to try cross-server features you can even create 2 servers being on different networks. If you use virtualization tools like vmware or virtualbox you can achieve it all on one computer, depends on your machine's specifics of course. Good luck!

Comment: This is the problem  var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]); Change it for  var formData = new FormData($('form#upppic'))[0]);

Comment: @FernandoUrban that doesn't make a difference, because of $("form#upppic").submit(function() the script presumes "this" = "form#upppic" I tried it just in case and still the same problem. the script works ok, on smaller images. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**
Got it working; as Vove suggested in the comments, I contacted my service provider and it mysteriously started working. The code is correct.